# Configure akka-http request timeout in Play2

Tags: playframework, timeout, akka-http

I'm making a long-running database call from my Play2.7 app and getting

```
DEBUG a.a.RepointableActorRef: 
Aborting tcp connection to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60454 because of upstream failure:
akka.http.impl.engine.HttpIdleTimeoutException: 
HTTP idle-timeout encountered, no bytes passed in the last 75 seconds. 
This is configurable by akka.http.[server|client].idle-timeout.
```

I tried to make it wait longer by modifying the setting mentioned in the output in my `src/main/resources/application.conf`. I also tried following Play2 documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/SettingsAkkaHttp and setting `play.server.akka.requestTimeout = "infinite"`
However, I still get that "75 seconds" message. How to override this timeout setting?

Comment: As the erorr says, have you tried this `akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 5s` ? Or  this `play.server.http.idleTimeout="infinite"` ?

Comment: @ssasi I believe I tried that. Sorry, no longer remember what  ended up with

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice explanation of the issue you're probably facing: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8286

Http server settings are ignored if you run the application with sbt run (which you probably are in your development environment). You need to declare these settings either in build.sbt or command line arguments.

Here is an example in build.sbt for play 2.8, setting the idle timeout to 5 minutes:

```
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.http.idleTimeout" -> "360000"
```